# Are linking verbs a sub-class of intrasitive or a distinct category?

Tags: verbs

Are **linking verbs** a sub-class of **intrasitive** or a **distinct category**?

Comment: It depends on the classification; some [traditional grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivity_(grammar)) and [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be) describe them as intransitive, but other schemes have more than two classes.

Comment: Now which one should we follow?

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is **complex intransitive.** Note that only "be" is termed 'copula'.

Comment: @BillJ "He is **in the room**." Is this a complex or ordinary intrasitive?

Comment: "In the room" is a complement, but it's not predicative. Clauses that do not contain predicative complements are ordinary intransitives. Clauses that do contain predicative complements are complex intransitives, e.g. "He felt angry".

Comment: @BillJ Okay. Thank you, sir.